# Is there a way to reference a custom shader from within the json material format in three.js?

Tags: javascript, three.js, shader

The JSON Object Scene format 4 for Three.js has a specification for materials defined here: [JSON Material Format 4](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/JSON-Material-format-4)

But it is not clear, at least not to me, how or weather it is possible to reference a custom shader from there. Any ideas how this can be done?

**[UPDATE]**

I guess my question was not clear enough what I am talking about is having the JSON loader be able to interpret a material define by a custom shader. This is an excerpt of the JSON Object Scene format 4:

```
"materials": [
    {
        "uuid": "87D95D6C-6BB4-4B8F-8166-A3A6945BA5E3",
        "type": "MeshPhongMaterial",
        "color": 16777215,
        "ambient": 16777215,
        "emissive": 0,
        "specular": 1118481,
        "shininess": 30,
        "opacity": 1,
        "transparent": false,
        "wireframe": false
    }
],
"object": {
    "uuid": "89529CC6-CBAC-412F-AFD1-FEEAE785BA19",
    "type": "Scene",
    "matrix": [1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1],
    "children": [
        {
            "uuid": "33FA38D9-0AAC-4657-9BBE-5E5780DDFB2F",
            "name": "Box 1",
            "type": "Mesh",
            "geometry": "C3BF1E70-0BE7-4E6D-B184-C9F1E84A3423",
            "material": "87D95D6C-6BB4-4B8F-8166-A3A6945BA5E3",
            "matrix": [1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1]
        },
```

As you can see, a mesh can reference a material by its UUID. The JSON loader, when loading this file, will check the type of this material, and based on it, create an instance of that material with the provided parameters. The problem that I have is that the types of materials are predefined inside the WebGLPrograms function and I can't find a clear way to extend this list with a custom shader.

Comment: Still very unclear to me. What list are you trying to _"extend"_ ? A `WebGLProgram` check only if it's dealing with a `RawShaderMaterial` or a `ShaderMaterial` which are the material types to use if you want to apply  custom shaders to geometries. You should add your code to clarify the question.

Comment: Let me explain it like this: the MaterialLoader class which takes care of creating the materials when you load a scene with the JSONLoader is able to create instances of all standard materials. But it is not clear if, or how, it would be possible to tell it to create an instance of a custom ShaderMaterial.

Comment: is it just a question of specifying the type as ShaderMaterial and pass uniforms, vertexShader and fragmentShader as parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a custom shader you have to implement a [ShaderMaterial](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/materials/ShaderMaterial) or a [RawShaderMaterial](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/materials/RawShaderMaterial) using the attributes `vertexShader`, `fragmentShader`, the code of both shaders has to be included in the html/js source.

As long as the source for both shaders is provided you can have a JSON format, a `ShaderMaterial` inherit from the base [Material](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/materials/Material.js) object.

With a no param `ShaderMaterial` you'll see both default vertex and fragment shaders code in the JSON output.

```js
var shader = new THREE.ShaderMaterial();
console.log(shader.toJSON());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r82/three.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

### Update:

Last attempt. Hope I understood your question update and comments correctly.

*But it is not clear if, or how, it would be possible to tell it to create an instance of a custom ShaderMaterial.*

Yes the `MaterialLoader` can load a `ShaderMaterial` with custom vertex and fragment shaders, the `Material.toJSON` method and the `MaterialLoader` are specular, as it should be, or it wouldn't make sense to convert a material to JSON format.

```js
// specular aspect of saving and loading
var loader = new THREE.MaterialLoader();

var shaderMaterial = new THREE.ShaderMaterial();
var shaderMaterialJSON = JSON.stringify(shaderMaterial.toJSON());

console.log('JSON ' + shaderMaterialJSON);

var loadedShaderMaterial = loader.parse(JSON.parse(shaderMaterialJSON));

console.log(loadedShaderMaterial);

// convert a phong material to a shader material
var phongMatJSON = '{"uuid": "87D95D6C-6BB4-4B8F-8166-A3A6945BA5E3", "type": "MeshPhongMaterial", "color": 16777215, "ambient": 16777215, "emissive": 0, "specular": 1118481, "shininess": 30, "opacity": 1, "transparent": false, "wireframe": false}';

var phongMatObj = JSON.parse(phongMatJSON);
phongMatObj.color = undefined; // not used in a shaderMaterial
phongMatObj.emissive = undefined; // not used in a shaderMaterial
phongMatObj.specular = undefined; // not used in a shaderMaterial
phongMatObj.name = '';
phongMatObj.type = 'ShaderMaterial';
phongMatObj.uniforms = {}
phongMatObj.vertexShader = 'void main() {\n\tgl_Position = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4( position, 1.0 );\n}';
phongMatObj.fragmentShader = 'void main() {\n\tgl_FragColor = vec4( 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0 );\n}';

var shaderMatObj = loader.parse(phongMatObj);

console.log(shaderMatObj);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/r82/three.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks @Marcs but this is not exactly what I was asking. If you have time check the clarification that I added above.